# Inverse, Converse and contraposition of statement?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to break the statements:

"Being rich is necessary for Alex to be happy"(1) and "Stop, or I will shoot!"(2)

(1) Statement

$\neg Rich \Rightarrow \neg Happy$

**Converse**

$\neg Happy \Rightarrow \neg Rich  $

**Inverse**

$ Rich \Rightarrow  Happy$

**Contrapositive**

$Happy \Rightarrow Rich  $

(2) Statement

$\neg Stop  \Rightarrow \neg Shot$

**Converse**

$\neg Shot \Rightarrow  \neg Stop $

**Inverse**

$ Stop  \Rightarrow  Shot$

**Contrapositive**

$Shot \Rightarrow   Stop $

Is this true?

I appreciate your answer!

***UPDATE***

(2) Statement

$\neg Stop  \Rightarrow Shot$

**Converse**

$ Shot \Rightarrow  \neg Stop $

**Inverse**

$ Stop  \Rightarrow  \neg Shot$

**Contrapositive**

$\neg Shot \Rightarrow   Stop $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answers to $(1)$ are just fine. You seem to understand the relationships between an implication, its converse, inverse, and its contrapositive.

> Implication: $A \equiv (p \rightarrow q)$

- converse of $A$: $\;q\rightarrow p$
- inverse of $A$: $\;\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$
- contrapositive: $\;\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$

Note that $\,A \equiv \text{contrapositive(A)}\;$ and $\;\text{inverse(A)}\equiv \text{converse(A)}$.

$(2)$ Here, your initial translation is incorrect, and as a consequence, so are the  converse, inverse, and contrapositives.

Let's look at $(2)$ again.

> Stop, or I'll shoot $\iff$ If you don't stop, then I'll shoot.

This can be translated into two equivalent logical statements:

$\text{Stop} \lor \text{Shot}\,\equiv \lnot \,\text{Stop}\rightarrow \text{Shot}\tag{2}$

Now, use what you know about the converse of an implication, the inverse, and the contrapositive to write the corresponding statements to the implication given on the right-hand side of $(2)$

---

**UPDATE**: Now you're spot on!

---

Comment: Thx for your answer! I updated my answer!

Comment: And you're spot on! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: What does it mean by saying Spot on?+

Comment: Hi, @Babak: it means: "indeed, you're understanding of the matter, and your answer, are entirely correct."

Comment: @amWhy: It even has a history! http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_origin_of_the_phrase_spot_on +1