# Rewriting conditional statement into contrapositive form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I had to rewrite:

"If Elizabeth has enough gas money to drive to California, then Elizabeth has enough gas money to drive to Las Vegas."

Into contrapositive form.

I rewrote it as:

If Elizabeth doesn't have enough money to drive to California, then Elizabeth won't have enough money to drive to LA.

Although I got this wrong, I'm not completely sure why. Can anyone tell me why.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455557/inverse-converse-and-contraposition-of-statement?rq=1)?

Comment: No...maybe LV costs $100$ and CA costs $110$ and she has $102$ or something like that.

Comment: It should be:  "If Elizabeth doesn't have enough gas money to Las Vegas, then Elizabeth doesn't have enough gas money to drive to California."

Comment: Given $p\rightarrow q$, his is equivalent to the contrapositive, which is $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$

Comment: @amWhy is it still an if then statement?

Comment: Yes it is. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of an implication $p \rightarrow q$ is the implication $\neg q \rightarrow \neg p$. Note that the constituent propositions $p$ and $q$ must be the *same ones* as in the original implication. In formal logic we are not allowed to use ordinary language reasoning about, say, cities in the United States, to rewrite statements.

Answer (score 0):

Even though a couple of comments and the other answer describe what the contrapositive is, I'd like to present this in a way that will hopefully click with you.

Imagine that the first sentence is true. That if Elizabeth has enough money (gas money to keep it simple) to drive to California, she will indeed have enough money to drive to Las Vegas. What would this mean for Elizabeth's starting point? That it is somewhere closer to LV than to California. Just to make things easier imagine she is driving from the east, say Colorado.

Now express the same idea, the same situation, but from a negative perspective: where Elizabeth **cannot** drive.  Is it the following?

> If Elizabeth doesn't have enough money to drive to California, then Elizabeth won't have enough money to drive to LA.

Well, this does not seem to express the same situation. If Elizabeth is coming from Colorado and cannot reach California, then **we do not know** whether she can reach Las Vegas or not. Maybe she has just enough money to reach LV (but not go much further) maybe not. So this statement does not work.

But **we do know** that if our original statement is true, then Elizabeth cannot drive to California if she cannot drive to LV. I hope this is obvious to you. This is the equivalent statement we are looking for.

> If Elizabeth doesn't have enough money to drive to LV, she doesn't have enough money to drive to California.

So if you think about it "logically", meaning in a common sense way, you should arrive to the contrapositive.

Finally some "theory". In general, the contrapositive is an **equivalent** statement to an original implication statement (meaning an `if-then` statement) formed in a specific way. We switch the order of the hypothesis and the conclusion in our `if-then` statement and we negate them both. Exactly what we did with our example above.
The two statements are equivalent in the sense that whenever one is true the other one is true too, and whenever one is false the other one is false too.