# Inverse and contrapositive of an 'if-then' statement

Tags: logic

I have the following original statement before me:
If $x>0$ & $y\leq0$ then $xy\leq0$ ($x$ and $y$ are real numbers).

I have to write its converse, inverse and contrapositive.
First of all ,the original statement is true. Hence its contrapositive should also be true. I wrote the converse as : If $xy<=0$ then $x>0$ and $y\leq0$. Converse is false as can be seen with the help of a counterexample. If I take $x=-5$ and $y=4$ then we can see that the converse is false.
Next I tried writing inverse as : If it is not the case that $x>0$ and $y\leq0$ then $xy>0$. Again inverse is false because for case $x<0$ and $y\geq 0$ which is a different case from $x>0$ and $y<=0$,  $xy<=0$. Inverse can also be written as   : If $x<=0$ or $y>0$ then $xy<0$. ( Negation of a conjunction is a disconnection.) In this form also we can see that inverse is false when we take $x=0$ and $y=4$.
Finally we come to contrapositive. I first write it as : If  $xy>0$ then it is not the case that $x>0$ and $y\leq 0$. This is obviously correct as should be the case as the original statement is true. But I completely lose it when I write it as: If $xy>0$ then $x\leq 0$ or $y>0$. In this form contrapositive seems false to me. If I explore $x\leq 0$ or $y>0$ further, it could be subdivided in three sub-cases:

1.$x\leq 0$ and $y\leq 0$.
2.$x>0$ and $y>0$.
3.$x\leq0$ and $y>0$.
Out of these three sub-cases, third case won't ever give me $xy>0$ and in the first sub-case, there is the possibility of getting $xy=0$. It is worth noting that the two cases which are implied when $xy>0$ i.e. either ($x>0$ and $y>0$) or ($x<0$ and $y<0$) are contained in 2nd and Ist sub-cases respectively.
It seems to me that in feeling that contrapositive is false, I am mixing different things. Please suggest where I am being incorrect.

Comment: I think the issue lies in recognizing that not all three subcases have to be satisfied. It suffices that at least one of them is valid.

Comment: fyi the code for for $\leq$ is \leq , likewise $\geq$ is \geq.

Comment: To say that "$xy\ge 0 \implies x\le 0$ or $y \gt 0$" is true is to say that whenever the premise is true the conclusion has to be true, not the other way around which is what you're doing with the cases you're considering.

Comment: See [Inverse, Converse, Contrapositive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455557/inverse-converse-and-contraposition-of-statement): apply the formula to your "if..., then..." statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to avoid casework:

As you say, the contrapositive of your statement is “if $xy > 0$, then it is not the case that both $x > 0$ and $y \le 0$“. However, this is logically equivalent to “if $xy > 0$, and in addition $x > 0$, then it must be the case that $y > 0$.” Why? We are assuming that if $xy > 0$, then the two statements $x > 0$ and $y \le 0$ cannot occur simultaneously. Therefore if $xy > 0$ holds and (without loss of generality) $x > 0$ holds, then the other statement $y \le 0$ *cannot* hold as well.

The upshot of this is that we can immediately divide both sides of $xy > 0$ by $x$ to conclude that $y > 0$ and the contrapositive is true. A similar process can help you reason through the converse.